# how to revert back data from table if entry is made by stored procedure which enters data in multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

how to revert back data from table if entry is made by stored procedure which enters data in multiple tables, but there is a error in data entry in one table. So now i have to revert back data from other tables too. How to do that?

Comment: Sorry,but your question is too general. You can update/delete error data

Comment: You can use transactions; be sure to add error and deadlock processing properly!

Comment: Generally speaking, you use transactions to force all changes to be either committed to together or rolled back. It sounds like you might be trying to do this after committing (perhaps caused by an accident or problem of some sort). If so, you are too late. There is no built-in functionality that will do what you want. You will need to manually "un-do" the changes yourself or attempt a point-in-time restore (which is likely beyond your abilities at this point).

Answer (score 2):

Use explicit transactions, and a `TRY...CATCH`. This is an basic example, but demonstrates the idea:

```sql
--Create Sampel tables

CREATE TABLE dbo.SampleTable1 (ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                               SomeString varchar(20));
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.SampleTable2 (ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                               fID int,
                               SomeInt int);

ALTER TABLE dbo.SampleTable2 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Sample2Sample1 FOREIGN KEY (fID) REFERENCES dbo.SampleTable1 (ID);

GO
--Workign sample
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION YourTransaction;

    INSERT INTO dbo.SampleTable1 (SomeString)
    VALUES('abc123');

    INSERT INTO dbo.SampleTable2 (fID, SomeInt)
    VALUES(1,2);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION YourTransaction;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION YourTransaction;

    THROW;
END CATCH;    

GO
--Failing example
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION YourTransaction;

    INSERT INTO dbo.SampleTable1 (SomeString)
    VALUES('def456');

    INSERT INTO dbo.SampleTable2 (fID, SomeInt)
    VALUES(3,2); --Invalid foreign key

    COMMIT TRANSACTION YourTransaction;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION YourTransaction;

    THROW;
END CATCH;  

GO

SELECT * --Notice ID 2 missing.
FROM dbo.SampleTable1;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.SampleTable2;
DROP TABLE dbo.SampleTable1;
```